# Поведение сборщика мусора для кода вне блока export?

Tags: vue.js, сборщик-мусора, export

Речь про довольно распространенный прием во vue, когда часть функционала выносится из блока export:

```
<script>
const outerData = Math.random();
const outerFunc = (data) => console.log(data);

export default {
    methods: {
         myMethod() {
             outerFunc(outerData);
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

- Любой код вне блока export во vue выполняется один раз во время компиляции.
- Код внутри export выполняется при импорте.
- При долгом простое GC удаляет из памяти все ссылки на неиспользуемые переменные.

Вопрос: если код выполняется только при импорте, а компонент долго не экспортировался, существует ли теоретическая возможность, что все ссылки компонента на внешние переменные могут оказаться утерянными?

Comment: GC сохраняет в памяти "код" в блоках "export". Вопрос в том, обходит ли GC рекурсивно этот код и кеширует ли зависимости экспортируемого кода?